# Open /wp-json response with "forbidden_access"

Tags: wordpress, api, rest

I installed a customer project on my local machine.

I want to create a new REST API route.

On the live website, i can see the wp-json data.

But when i call the wp-json on localhost, i get this message:

[image]

I have a couple of wordpress websites on localhost and everyone work without any problems. Instead of this wordpress installation. I already uninstalled all plugins and the message still appear.

Has anyone an idea to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

This could be a permalink issue, go to Settings > Permalinks and change the setting to "Post name"  and save settings, then check if you get the same issue or not.